# Mysterious appearance of white space on the right pf my parallax page

Tags: html, css

Up until a forced reboot, my parallax scrolling page was working fine. Now though, a mysterious whitespace is offsetting the sections. It only appears every other section - one section is ok, the next below is offset, etc.

I've checked through the css that styles and positions the parallax sections, but haven't found any margins, padding or other offsets that could be causing the offset.

please have a look [here](http://wearerain.co/test/s-index.html).

Comment: Appears to be ok on mobile, and when I inspect in Chrome with responsive toggle, it also disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Only every second section has parallax. So it’s nothing about being every nth section.

There is a class `.parallax__layer--back` which has `transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2)`. When I changed it to `translateZ(-295px) scale(2)` it filled whole space. The other section has `translateZ(-600px) scale (3)` and there I had to use `-289px`. Looks like transform is not working for you how’d you expect.

Comment: "The other section has translateZ(-600px) scale (3) and there I had to use -289px. Looks like transform is not working for you how’d you expect."
Which section did you see that?
That's a huge change. Up until now all my testing hasn't revealed any problem with transforms at all. Now all of a sudden, this.

Comment: Can I ask which device and browser you've viewing in too?

Comment: I was using Firefox on Windows 10. Second section had “fix” with `-295px`, the other one was “Digital sustainability”.